# overriding node check by xsl compile

Tags: xml, xslt

I wish be build the following xsl structure below:

```
<body>
<item></item>
<item></item>
<item></item>
</body>
```

the number of items between the body node is variable so I want to call a template with param 'place' where if the value is start or end the body node is created or closed respectively. The basic code structure is below. The issue i have is that its not possible to use this method as you cant have the node open when closing the when statement. How can I override this behaviour of the xsl compiler

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$place='start'">
   <body>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$place='end'">
   </body>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: That's not the right approach, can the number of item to add passed to the transform as a parameter?

Comment: yes the number of items will be known when calling the template so can be passed as a param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to call a template with param 'place' where if the value is
>   start or end the body node is created or closed respectively

This is impossible. You cannot have incorrectly nested tags in XSLT (just like you cannot have incorrectly nested braces/parentheses/control structures in *any other programming language*).

Luckily, this is also completely unnecessary. This will do what you want:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item" /> 
  </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <!-- whatever you want to do with the items -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
<xsl:param name="tot" select="3"/>

<xsl:template match="body">
  <body>
    <xsl:call-template name="add-items" /> 
  </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="add-items">
 <xsl:param name="num" select="1"/>
 <item />
 <xsl:if test="$num &lt; $tot">
  <xsl:call-template name="add-items">
   <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num + 1"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT doesn't "create" and "close" nodes as separate operations: you can't do one and not the other. It builds a result tree, and a node either exists on the result tree or it doesn't. You're thinking about tags when you need to think about a tree of nodes.